# Getting an error while trying to deploy with Modolus

Tags: telescope

I am following [this tutorial (using meteor on modulus)](http://help.modulus.io/customer/portal/articles/1647770-using-meteor-with-modulus) to test telescope app and how the deploy works

I am getting this error :

> Unable to connect to any application instances.

And this is the log:

> /mnt/data/1/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
>                         throw(ex);
>                               ^ TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
>       at app/server/migrations.js:469:43
>       at [object Object]._.extend.forEach (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:965:1)
>       at [object Object].Cursor.(anonymous function) [as forEach] (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:812:1)
>       at Object.migrationsList.updateUserNames (app/server/migrations.js:462:14)
>       at runMigration (app/server/migrations.js:45:52)
>       at app/server/migrations.js:10:5
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at Function.*.each.*.forEach (packages/underscore/underscore.js:105:1)
>       at Meteor.methods.removeMigration.Migrations.remove.name (app/server/migrations.js:9:5)
>       at /mnt/data/1/programs/server/boot.js:229:5 [2015-04-09T22:31:49.395Z] Failed to start application.

Thank you !!

Comment: the app works fine local?

Answer (score 2):

This is a common issue when you don't redeploy the application after the first step.

run this 2 commands.

```
modulus project restart
modulus deploy
```

**NOTE** be sure the URL don't have any blank space either.

Answer (score 0):

From step three of the tutorial,

> The Meteor app is not quite ready yet and the logs will show errors. We have to deploy first in order to receive a URL for Meteor's required environment variables.

Have you goen through and correctly defined all of the environment variables?